# Check if the parabola (with an induced topology) $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 | y=x^2\}$ is connected or compact.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

i think yes connected but not compact, as it cannot be represented as a disjoint union and there is no finite sub cover. I'm just not sure how to go about proving this i.e. what to actually write down. could you say the function is continuous and therefore connected? for compactedness can you state it is clear the interval (-inf, inf) has no finite sub cover, not too sure

Comment: Cover the parabola with balls centred at each point $(n,n^2)$ for integer $n$ with radius $0.9$. Every integer-coordinate point is only covered by one ball, so there is no proper subcover at all, much less a finite one that covers the parabola.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For compactness, recall that $\Bbb R = \pi(P)$ where $P$ is the graph of parabola, and $\pi$ is the projection on the first coordinate. If $P$ would be compact, so would be $\pi(P)$ since $\pi$ is a continuous map.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove non-compactness by finding a discrete closed infinite subset (think the points whose $x$ coordinate is integer). Connectedness is even easier, as it's the image of $\mathbb R$ by a continuous function (continuous functions take connected sets to connected sets).